# Predicate calculus question

Tags: logic

I have got the next structure: $M =<${1,2,3,4,5}$,S^M>$ such that: $S^M$ = {$<x,y>\mid y-x=1$}. Need to find the truth value of the next sentence: $$\exists x \forall y \exists z[\lnot [S(x,z)\lor x=z\ \lor S(y,z)\ \lor y=z]]$$

How do you suggest to do that?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In the formula you have to write $S$ and not $S^M$

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I didn't notice. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that $\phi = \exists x \forall y \exists z(\lnot (S(x,z)\lor x=z\ \lor S(y,z)\ \lor y=z))$ is a sentence, hence its truth set can be either

- $M^3$ if $M$ satisfies $\phi$; or
- the empty set if $M$ doesn't satisfy $\phi$.

In the first case the truth value is $1$, $0$ otherwise. Is it true that $\exists x \forall y \exists z(\lnot (S(x,z)\lor x=z\ \lor S(y,z)\ \lor y=z))$? Well, I think so. Fix $x=1$. If you choose $y=1,2,3$ I pick $z=3,4,5$; if you choose $y=4,5$ I pick $z=3,3$ and $\lnot (S(x,z)\lor x=z\ \lor S(y,z)\ \lor y=z))$ is satisfied.

Comment: Do you have a more general answer? I got that this is false...

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What do you mean by 'more general'?

Comment: I mean that not on the way of $\forall$ picking numbers, and then $\exists$ picking too, and so on...